# Combine two SQL query calls into one in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have a stored procedure named `find_slow_persons()` that returns a table with two columns:

```
RETURNS TABLE(
        person_id           BIGINT,
        time_late_by        DOUBLE PRECISION
        )
```

and with Hibernate, I can obtain these 2 column's values as `List` with 2 calls:

```
 SQLQuery query =
                session.createSQLQuery("select * from find_slow_persons()").addScalar("person_id", LongType.INSTANCE);

 SQLQuery time =
                session.createSQLQuery("select * from find_slow_persons()").addScalar("time_late_by",
                        LongType.INSTANCE);
List<Long> duplicateDataPointIds = query.list();
List<Long> timeBy = time.list();
```

Now I got the 2 lists of the data I want, is there a way to combine these 2 and only make 1 query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you're separating the column into two queries? The following should have the desired effect if not:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from find_slow_persons()")
               .addScalar("person_id", LongType.INSTANCE)
               .addScalar("time_late_by", LongType.INSTANCE)
// returns an object[] List you'll have to unpack
List duplicateDataPointIds = query.list();
```

Comment: I tried to print out the Object array it returned, why is it missing a closing ] at the end?

Comment: The object array doens't have a toString() method that will pretty print it since it doesn't know the types, try casting them to Longs